# how to get the objects under the mouse - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

how to get the objects under the mouse - Unity

I need to capture a specific object in my scene that is under the mouse pointer. any code that can do that?

Comment: well if it has a collider, you can use OnMouseEnter for each object, or, you raycast and raycast from your mouse position and see what it hits.. why what did you try and what problems did you have?

Comment: I am using an onMouseEnter2D and onMouseExit2D in a static Collider. And I also have a dynamic Collider that eventually runs over the static Collider. The problem I have is that when the mouse is over the static Collider, the OnMouseEnter2D is activated, but when the dynamic Collider passes over this static Collider, OnMouseExit2D of the static Collider is activated. And I want OnMouseEnter2D and OnMouseExit2D to work without being affected by the Dynamic Collider.

Comment: so this problem makes me think that there must be some way to capture all the objects that are under the mouse pointer.

Comment: See my first comment

Comment: i read, but the problem is when the dynamic Collider passes over this static Collider, The OnMouseExit2D of the static Collider is activated. and then the OnMouseEnter2D is activated again when the dinamic collider of the dinamic collider leaves the area.

Comment: all this happens without moving the mouse. both functions are activated and deactivated only because another object with collider passes over my static object

Comment: .....  if something is in front then it will be not the item the mouse is over.. raycast can ignore certainly layers if you tell it.. but you need to test it

Comment: i try use raycast, but how to capture the objects?
Vector3 ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray, ray);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("hit");
        }

Comment: well if you use the right one it lists ALL objects it hits, that one only reports the first.. and the hit.collider.gameobect is the object it his

Comment: any example plz

Comment: Unity provides great examples. As well as plenty of other people have already asked this

Comment: thanks friend, your answers have not helped me. I'll keep looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution

```
int layerObject = 8;
Vector2 ray = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray, ray, layerObject);
if (hit.collider != null)
{
    Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<YourObject>().YouAttribute);
}
```